# jqtransform and collapsed DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I am using a jQuery plugin called: [jqtransform](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqtransform)

This plugin uses JavaScript to apply CSS styles to form elements.

**The problem that I have consists in the following scenario:**

I’m building a search page, with a advanced search option.
When the page loads, the div called “advancedSearch” is hidden, and it will only show if the user clicks a  element. Inside the div#advancedSearch I have several form elements.

However, if I hide the div#advancedSearch with the CSS style: “diplay:none;”, the jqtransform plugin doesn’t work correctly with the elements that are hidden. So my solution was to hide the div#advancedsearch with JavaScript. This actually works, and it does not matter if it’s done after the document is ready or not.

But… with the JavaScript solution, the div#advancedSearch stays visible for a couple of milliseconds… which is visually annoying.

So I was wondering if the solution to this problem would be in the CSS, or in correcting the jqtransform plugin, or even in finding a way to immediately hide the div#advancedSearch with JS making it immediately hidden.

---

### UPDATE 1

**After jeerose comment I decided to place here my function**
*(please note that the <%= %> are ASP.Net tags, that I use to get the images path)*

```
$('.toggleAdvancedSearch').click(function() {
    $('#advancedSearchWrap').slideToggle(250);
    $('form.jqtransform').jqTransform({ imgPath: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/masterpages/img/jqtransform/") %>' });
    return false;
});
```

---

### UPDATE 2

**To test the problem, I did the following:**

Added another  element to the page, with the ID “applyStyle”, and onClick I call the $('form').jqTransform();

Disabled the the $('form').jqTransform(); from the load of the page.

If I press the a#applyStyle, before expanding the div#advancedSearch I get the same problem that I had.

But if I expand the the div#advancedSearch and press the the a#applyStyle after, the problem is solved.

However, if I run the page with the $('form').jqTransform(); function on the load, I cannot reapply it after with the pressing of the a#applyStyle.

**I think that the solution could be:** disabling the all the elements that are inside the div#advancedSearch, and on the same function that expands the div, make It also apply the styles to the elements that are inside the div#advancedSearch.

**However, I don’t know how to do this** (nether if this will work).

---

*PS: This seems to be a known issue with the plugin, but I cannot wait indefinitely for a solution.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having a completely different problem, so I figured I'd type this up along with the solution so people can hopefully find it ...

jqtransform applies z-index values to all select dropdowns (in this case elements, not options), and it does this starting from 10 downwards. This means that the 2nd select box will have a z-index of 9, 3rd 8, 4th 7 etc ... If you have more than 11, you will get into negatives. This causes big problems in case your select boxes are in a more complicated div set where z-index values are of importance (they basically dissapear in the background).

To fix this problem, it is probably a good idea to amend the jqtransform code so it uses the selectbox tabindex attribute as the z-index for the new selecbox that it creates. This way, all new (makeshift and styled) selectboxes will have a z-index value of the real hidden selectbox tabindex attribute.

Basically the code from line 256 to 261 (or there abouts) should look something like this:

```
var $wrapper = $select
                .addClass('jqTransformHidden')
                .wrap('<div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper"></div>')
                .parent()
                .css({zIndex: $select.attr('tabindex')})
            ;
```

To use this set a tab index on the selectbox .. eg:

```
<select name="blah" id="blah" tabindex="33">...</select>
```

This is nifty as you can control which select box appears above others. So make the tabindexes decrease down the page. You don't want dropdowns appearing below other select boxes beneath.

keywords: jqtransform dropdowns selectbox dropdown box selects z-index invisible

Comment: Thank you for this, I keep having problems with this plugin, I can't believe the author didn't think having more than 10 selects could be a possibility...

Answer (score 1):

I've done this and it works great:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('p.panel_class').click(function () {                     
    $('form.jqtransform').jqTransform(
        $('form#panel').slideToggle('fast'))    
    }); });
```

I hope this will help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the z-index on the select dropdowns and a relatively positioned fieldset below my last dropdown. Any dropdown that had a negative z-index was hidden by the relatively positioned fieldset below it.

To "fix" the problem, I just increased the z-index from 10 to 100.

```
        var $wrapper = $select
            .addClass('jqTransformHidden')
            .wrap('<div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper"></div>')
            .parent()
            .css({zIndex: 100-index})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fix is already mentioned, but when encountering initiating problems like this (and I had many, not just with `jqtransform`), instead of using `display:none`, I use `position:absolute` and `left: -10000px`, showing it to the user again by `display:relative` `left:auto`. That way the element is available for script targeting while invisible to the user. 
Depending on the structure of the site it might be necessary to give it's holder fixed dimensions, since the element itself is removed from the flow of the document and layout may collapse when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a function for when a user selects the advanced option and these new elements are displayed. In that case can you call the plugin initializer again?

```
$('#advanceSearchButton').click(function(){    
    $('#AdvanceSearch').show('slow', function(){
        $('form.jqtransform').jqTransform(); 
    });
});
```

This way you can start with your #AdvanceSearch div set to display:none and avoid the momentary display of the element.

**Update:** 
To be clear, have you added it as a callback function? This will ensure that it will fire after the effect has completed.

```
$('#advancedSearchWrap').slideToggle(250, function(){
    $('form.jqtransform').jqTransform({ imgPath: 'asp path' }); 
    return false; 
});
```

This would go inside your click handler.

Comment: I have updated my post, in order to show you how i am making the 2nd call to the jqTransform plugin. I also tried to do it has you said, but it still wasn't working.

Comment: First of all: thank you very much for your replies. I tried to do what you told me, again, but I still didn't make. However, just to test i created two buttons, one that just expands the div, and anotherone to apply the plugin. My plan was to check if it would apply the plugin with the div opened... and it didn't!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem without the time to actually spend on working out a full fix, but for now if you add the code to close the panel you want hidden to end of the actual jquery.jqtransform.js file then the code to create all the dropdowns etc is completed before the div is hidden.

Using jquery i added the following to hide my div with call "filterContents".

```
$(".filterContents").hide(); 
}); /* End Form each */
```

Hope this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of setting the `display:none` you set its `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but here is how I solved the problem on my website.

Instead using `display:none` in CSS to hide the form I'm using `height:0;overflow:hidden`.

Next, in my js I'm using `animate` instead `slideToggle` I was using before to display the form. In my case code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
      $('#showAdvanced').toggle(function() {
        $('#sfBlock03').animate({
          height: 350
        });
      }, function() {
        $('#sfBlock03').animate({
          height: 0
        });
      });
    });
```

**Note:** `#showAdvaced` is the id of the button to show advanced options and `#sfBlock03` is the id of the div containing advanced form.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is new library I’ve created – csTransPie – basing it on jqtransform – jqtransform is a great library but it really has many problems, today css3 solves many of those problems and I like the idea of controls being normal controls and looking the same in every browser
https://github.com/pkoretic/csTransPie

It’s a work in progress but even now it’s better than jqtransform (more than half of the css rewritten, many bugs solved, clean css…)

now you can use it per element with just one class!

all suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can always recalculate the height of unordered list that holds your elements by doing this:

```
$(".open_my_popup").click(function(){
    $(".popup").fadeIn(200); //the popup part

//the recalculation part for jqtransform
    $(".jqTransformSelectWrapper").each(function(){ //remember to relaculate for each select! not for all at once, cause this will return problems
        var items = $(this).find("li").length
        var height = $(this).find("ul li > a").height(); //corresponds with css .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a height
        var list = $(this).find("ul");
        list.css("height",(items*height)+"px");
    });
});
```

You also need to remember that in the jqtransform.css the anchor element needs to be described like this:

```
.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:22px !important;
    height:22px !important;
}
```

By default in jqTransform styles there is: padding:5px; - and thanks to this padding the text is centered verticaly in the li element, this you need to change like i did using line-height and height because otherwise you wont recalculate proper height for the unordered list that holds all elements.